# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to run a Java project using page factory and page object model, I want to run it on Chrome, IE and on Firefox, but I am not able to run it on Firefox, the browser is not opening, I am getting this error : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/ElementTraversal`

My Code is :

```
@BeforeMethod
public static void openBrowser() {
    String browser = "";
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\test\\Resources\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }
    else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src\\test\\Resources\\BrowserDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
    }
    else {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@AfterMethod
public  static void closeBrowser(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: You need to have xml-apis....jar in your classpath. U using a build tool like Maven? Else it is included in the selenium jar...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See e.g. this [Github issue](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5245), some dependencies can drag in an outdated version of xml-apis which can cause this, a solution that worked for me was to add a specific dependency on xml-apis, e.g. with Maven something like

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.01</version>
</dependency>
```