# Updating to htmlunit 2.37.0: setTimeout() build failure

Tags: java, htmlunit

Hej.

First of all: sorry for maybe asking a very simple question, I am very new to Java.

Here is my problem: I updated the dependenciy of an ancient code from using `net.sourceforge.htmlunit` version 2.8 to 2.37.0 (this was recommended by the Github security bot).

Now my code is not compiling and throws two errors.

Here is the relevant code:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;

...

WebClient webClient = new WebClient(FIREFOX_3);
webClient.setTimeout(50000);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://king.smith.man.ac.uk/mcpred/");
```

1. First error:

```
[ERROR] ./MissedCleavageAnalysisAdaptor.java:[64,53] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   variable FIREFOX_3
```

2. Second error:

```
[ERROR] ./MissedCleavageAnalysisAdaptor.java:[65,26] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   method setTimeout(int)
```

I managed to avoid the first error by simply deleting the "FIREFOX_3". Using "FIREFOX" (= newest version of firefox) or "FIREFOX_78" instead did not work and threw the same error.

With the second error, I cannot see the problem. I tried other integers or first defining an integer `int timeout = 50000;` and `webClient.setTimeout(timeout);`. Always the same error occurs. It seems like the method `setTimeout` was not imported. However, this should be imported together with `WebClient`, shouldn't it?

Can you please give me a hint how to tackle these errors?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow thats a huge jump 2.8 was released Aug 5, 2010 and 2.37 in January 28, 2020.
The current version is 2.46.0 rom January 2, 2021 - maybe it makes sense to directly migrate to this one.

If you have a look at the release notes you will find this line:

> WebClient: deprecated setTimeout() and getTimeout(). Use webClient.getOptions() instead.

for the release 2.11. Means - you have to change your code like this:

```
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(50000);
```

The whole release notes are available here https://htmlunit.sourceforge.io/changes-report.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! As recommended, I directly upgraded to 2.46.0. About my the first error: I found out that I had to change to `WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX);`

Comment: Hum, now the compile runs without error, but the `jar` does not execute anymore... Seems to be more work than expected.

Comment: Ok, I also had to add a new dependency `xml-apis`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40912602/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-w3c-dom-elementtraversal). Interestingly, it did not work with the newest version (2.0.2), but with version 1.4.01. Now everything works.